# Expire fragment caching when inner HTML has changed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, fragment-caching

I have the following in my users.html.slim view:

```
.header
  Welcome
  - cache ['user/details', user.last_modified] do
    = render 'user/details', user: @user
```

My problem is that I have changed the `user/details` markup, and since the users haven't actually changed I still get the cached version.

According to the docs, since the HTML has changed, the cache should expire

> Cache fragments will also be expired when the view fragment changes
>   (e.g., the HTML in the view changes). The string of characters at the
>   end of the key is a template tree digest. It is an MD5 hash computed
>   based on the contents of the view fragment you are caching. If you
>   change the view fragment, the MD5 hash will change, expiring the
>   existing file.

But that doesn't seem to be the case.

What is the proper way of solving this scenario? Where the parameters that you rely on the keys haven't changed, but the actual markup has changed. I am thinking on doing something like:

```
- cache ['user/details/v2', user.last_modified] do
    = render 'user/details', user: @user
```

But I am wondering if that's what is more appropriate in these scenarios.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `user.last_modified` just pass `user`.

This will create a cache key based on the `user.id` and `user.updated_at`.

If `last_modified` is in fact the thing that you want to be the cache key, you reference `@user` but your cache key is `user`.

Comment: The user hasn't been updated or changed. What it has changed is the markup on the user/details partial. That is what my question is about.

Comment: I would add the cache inside of the partial. It should expire also when the file is modified.